# Getting Exception when used next() on iterator, after fetching data with hql query even though data is present

Tags: hibernate, java-8, query-optimization, hql, hibernate-mapping

The following is the Hql query which i am using. I am printing the customerRequestDetails, data is present. But when i use iterator on that set object and call next() I am getting exception. But if I remove group by from below query no exception is coming, but duplicate data coming without group by.

**Query with group by :**

```
from
    CustomerTravelRequest customerTravelRequest
    left join fetch customerTravelRequest.customer  customer
    left join fetch customer.rewardProgram rewardProgram
    join fetch customerTravelRequest.customerRequestDetails customerRequestDetails  
where
    (customerTravelRequest.requestStatus LIKE 'OPEN' OR customerTravelRequest.requestStatus LIKE 'BLOCK' OR customerTravelRequest.requestStatus LIKE 'FOLLOWUP') AND
    customer.id = ? AND
    customerTravelRequest.companyId=:companyId
    group by customerTravelRequest.id
    order by customerRequestDetails.id
```

**Query without group by :**

```
from
    CustomerTravelRequest customerTravelRequest
    left join fetch customerTravelRequest.customer  customer
    left join fetch customer.rewardProgram rewardProgram
    left join fetch customerTravelRequest.customerRequestDetails customerRequestDetails
where
    (customerTravelRequest.requestStatus LIKE 'OPEN' OR customerTravelRequest.requestStatus LIKE 'BLOCK' OR customerTravelRequest.requestStatus LIKE 'FOLLOWUP') AND
    customer.id = ? AND
    customerTravelRequest.companyId=:companyId
```

**Entity classes are as follows:**

```
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER_REQUEST_INFO")
@Audited
public class CustomerTravelRequest extends CompanyIdDto {

private Set<CustomerRequestDetails> customerRequestDetails;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerTravelRequest", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
@OptimisticLock(excluded = true)
@OrderBy
public Set<CustomerRequestDetails> getCustomerRequestDetails() {
    return customerRequestDetails;
}

/**
 * @param customerRequestDetails the customerRequestDetails to set
 */
public void setCustomerRequestDetails(Set<CustomerRequestDetails> customerRequestDetails) {
    this.customerRequestDetails = customerRequestDetails;
}
}

@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER_REQUEST_DETAILS")
@Audited
public class CustomerRequestDetails extends BaseDto {

private CustomerTravelRequest customerTravelRequest;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_REQUEST_ID")
@OptimisticLock(excluded = true)
public CustomerTravelRequest getCustomerTravelRequest() {
    return customerTravelRequest;
}

/**
 * @param customerTravelRequest the customerTravelRequest to set
 */
public void setCustomerTravelRequest(CustomerTravelRequest customerTravelRequest) {
    this.customerTravelRequest = customerTravelRequest;
}
}
```

Exception I am getting:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:742) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$IteratorProxy.next(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:789) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at com.yanasoftware.flights.admin.agency.service.impl.CustomerEventServiceImpl.isDuplicateCustomerTravelRequest(CustomerEventServiceImpl.java:172) ~[deployment/:3.0.1-dev]
    at com.yanasoftware.flights.admin.agency.service.impl.CustomerEventServiceImpl.closeDuplicateCustomerTravelRequestForTheCustomer(CustomerEventServiceImpl.java:88) ~[deployment/:3.0.1-dev]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy478.closeDuplicateCustomerTravelRequestForTheCustomer(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.yanasoftware.flights.admin.agency.service.impl.CustomerTravelRequestHistoryServiceImpl.createOrUpdateCustomerTravelRequestHistory(CustomerTravelRequestHistoryServiceImpl.java:55) [deployment/:3.0.1-dev]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) [spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) [spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy175.createOrUpdateCustomerTravelRequestHistory(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at com.yanasoftware.flightservice.service.impl.ItineraryServiceImpl.sendBookingConfirmationFollowUpAndVerificationEmails(ItineraryServiceImpl.java:1483) [deployment/:3.0.1-dev]
    at com.yanasoftware.flightservice.service.impl.ItineraryServiceImpl.storeBookedFlight(ItineraryServiceImpl.java:263) [deployment/:3.0.1-dev]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) [spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) [spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy304.storeBookedFlight(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:233) [groovy-all-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56) [groovy-all-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-all-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-all-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at com.indianeagle.ota.utils.CheckoutUtils.bookSelectedFlight(CheckoutUtils.groovy:2707) [classes/:?]
    at com.indianeagle.ota.utils.CheckoutUtils$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3681600e.invoke(<generated>) [?:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:651) [spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.indianeagle.ota.utils.CheckoutUtils$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9661fb89.bookSelectedFlight(<generated>) [?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210) [groovy-all-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71) [groovy-all-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-all-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-all-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at com.indianeagle.ota.controller.CheckoutController.validatePaymentAndBookFlight(CheckoutController.groovy:1172) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:52) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:233) [groovy-all-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56) [groovy-all-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) [groovy-all-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at com.indianeagle.ota.seo.web.filter.ErrorHandleFilter.doFilter(ErrorHandleFilter.groovy:46) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:176) [spring-orm-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2522) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2511) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.65]
```

**Following are the configurations**

- Java version 1.8
- tomcat 7
- my sql version 5.1.22
- commons-dbcp 1.4
- Spring application version : 4.1.4
- Hibernate version : 4.3.8.Final

This exception is not coming while running test case, this is coming only when application is running on server.

**EDIT 1**

in the following manner am accessing requestdetails

```
Iterator<CustomerRequestDetails> customerRequestDetailsIterator = customerTravelRequest.getCustomerRequestDetails().iterator();
    Iterator<CustomerRequestDetails> dupCustomerRequestDetailsIterator = duplicateCustomerTravelRequest.getCustomerRequestDetails().iterator();
    CustomerRequestDetails customerRequestDetails = customerRequestDetailsIterator.next();
    CustomerRequestDetails dupCustomerRequestDetails = dupCustomerRequestDetailsIterator.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to show us the code of `CustomerEventServiceImpl` to help you further, but I guess you are altering a `LinkedHashMap` while iterating it or something like that. Also, note that Hibernate 4.3 is very old now, so even if there is a bug in Hibernate, nobody will be able to help you at this point. It's time to update ;)

Comment: I have edited my question with code, Can you please check once. Thank you.

Comment: Did you check if the collection even has elements? It seems to me that one collection is empty.

Comment: Yes, I have checked collection is not empty. I am printing the data. For one CustomerTravelRequest we can have multiple request details. If I join them am getting same customerTravelRequest multiple times, So i used group by. Then this exception is coming while iterating. The same Exception is not coming at test case level.